# multiple criteria for aggregation on pySpark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pySpark dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-------------+----------+
|          sku|      date|
+-------------+----------+
|MLA-603526656|02/09/2016|
|MLA-603526656|01/09/2016|
|MLA-604172009|02/10/2016|
|MLA-605470584|02/09/2016|
|MLA-605502281|02/10/2016|
|MLA-605502281|02/09/2016|
+-------------+----------+
```

I want to group by sku, and then calculate the min and max dates. If I do this:

```
df_testing.groupBy('sku') \
    .agg({'date': 'min', 'date':'max'}) \
    .limit(10) \
    .show()
```

the behavior is the same as Pandas, where I only get the `sku` and `max(date)` columns. In Pandas I would normally do the following to get the results I want:

```
df_testing.groupBy('sku') \
    .agg({'day': ['min','max']}) \
    .limit(10) \
    .show()
```

However on pySpark this does not work, and I get a `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String` error. Could anyone please point me to the correct syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You cannot use dict. Use:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>>
>>> df_testing.groupBy('sku').agg(F.min('date'), F.max('date'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem. Initially I tried `from pyspark.sql.functions import  min, max` and the approach you propose, just without the F. Maybe python was confusing the SQL functions with the native ones.

Comment: I mean, I wouldn't exactly call this an answer, since it doesn't solve the issue of having to essentially denormalize your dictionary. Oh my mistake! It does solve the original question, but the denormalization issue still stands.