# Multiple aggregations on multiple columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Python in a Pyspark framework.
I am trying to apply different aggregations on different columns using `groupby`

I have a df with columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`
I want to do something like:
`df.groupby("col1").sum("col2", "col3").avg("col4")`

But I am getting an error:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'avg'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1301, in **getattr**
>       "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.**class**.**name**, name))
>   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'avg'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple criteria for aggregation on pySpark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274508/multiple-criteria-for-aggregation-on-pyspark-dataframe) and [Multiple Aggregate operations on the same column of a spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954771/multiple-aggregate-operations-on-the-same-column-of-a-spark-dataframe) and [Spark SQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/spark-sql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I am doing it in my modules:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as Functions

df2=df.groupBy('col1').agg(Functions.sum('col2'),Functions.sum('col3'),Functions.avg('col4'))
```