# pyspark collect_set of column outside of groupby

Tags: group-by, pyspark, set, collect

I am trying to use collect_set to get a list of strings of categorie_names that are **NOT** part of groupby.
My code is

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sc = SparkContext("local")
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
     ("1", "cat1", "Dept1", "product1", 7),
     ("2", "cat2", "Dept1", "product1", 100),
     ("3", "cat2", "Dept1", "product2", 3),
     ("4", "cat1", "Dept2", "product3", 5),
    ], ["id", "category_name", "department_id", "product_id", "value"])

df.show()
df.groupby("department_id", "product_id")\
    .agg({'value': 'sum'}) \
    .show()

#            .agg( F.collect_set("category_name"))\
```

The output is

```
+---+-------------+-------------+----------+-----+
| id|category_name|department_id|product_id|value|
+---+-------------+-------------+----------+-----+
|  1|         cat1|        Dept1|  product1|    7|
|  2|         cat2|        Dept1|  product1|  100|
|  3|         cat2|        Dept1|  product2|    3|
|  4|         cat1|        Dept2|  product3|    5|
+---+-------------+-------------+----------+-----+

+-------------+----------+----------+
|department_id|product_id|sum(value)|
+-------------+----------+----------+
|        Dept1|  product2|         3|
|        Dept1|  product1|       107|
|        Dept2|  product3|         5|
+-------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to have this output

```
+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|department_id|product_id|sum(value)| collect_list(category_name)|
+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|        Dept1|  product2|         3|  cat2                      |
|        Dept1|  product1|       107|  cat1, cat2                |
|        Dept2|  product3|         5|  cat1                      |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+
```

**Attempt 1**

```
df.groupby("department_id", "product_id")\
    .agg({'value': 'sum'}) \
    .agg(F.collect_set("category_name")) \
    .show()
```

I got this error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`category_name`'
>   given input columns: [department_id, product_id,
>   sum(value)];;\n'Aggregate [collect_set('category_name, 0, 0) AS
>   collect_set(category_name)#35]\n+- Aggregate [department_id#2,
>   product_id#3], [department_id#2, product_id#3, sum(value#4L) AS
>   sum(value)#24L]\n   +- LogicalRDD [id#0, category_name#1,
>   department_id#2, product_id#3, value#4L]\n"

**Attempt 2** I put category_name as part of groupby

```
df.groupby("category_name", "department_id", "product_id")\
    .agg({'value': 'sum'}) \
    .agg(F.collect_set("category_name")) \
    .show()
```

It works but output is not correct

```
+--------------------------+
|collect_set(category_name)|
+--------------------------+
|              [cat1, cat2]|
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [specify multiple aggregations within one `agg()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274508/multiple-criteria-for-aggregation-on-pyspark-dataframe). The correct syntax for your case would be:

```
df.groupby("department_id", "product_id")\
    .agg(F.sum('value'), F.collect_set("category_name"))\
    .show()
#+-------------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
#|department_id|product_id|sum(value)|collect_set(category_name)|
#+-------------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
#|        Dept1|  product2|         3|                    [cat2]|
#|        Dept1|  product1|       107|              [cat1, cat2]|
#|        Dept2|  product3|         5|                    [cat1]|
#+-------------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Your method doesn't work, because the first `.agg()` works on a `pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData` and returns a new DataFrame. The subsequent call to `agg` is actually [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg) which is

> shorthand for `df.groupBy.agg()`

So essentially the second call to `agg` is grouping again, which is not what you intended.